# How can i get a Qlik app layout as XML/JSON File?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

What is the simplest way to view the structure/layout of my Qlik dashboards in the form of XML or JSON files in Qlik Sense Desktop?
So it should contain detailed informaions about visualizations & styles.

Is building a (Python) script to access information via the Qlik Engine JSON API the right approach?

**Update 1 current Code**

```
(async () => {
  const { docMixin } = await import("enigma-mixin");
  const fs = require('fs');
  const enigma = require('enigma.js');
  const WebSocket = require('ws');
  const schema = require('enigma.js/schemas/12.612.0.json');

  // create a new session:
  const session = enigma.create({
      schema,
      mixins: [docMixin],
      url: 'ws://localhost:9076/app/engineData',
      createSocket: url => new WebSocket(url),
  });

  async function run() {
      const global = await session.open()

      // change to your appId
      const doc = await global.openDoc("My_App")

      const entities = await doc.mUnbuild()

      await session.close()
  }

  await run();
})();
```

**Output**

```
const entities = await doc.mUnbuild()
                                 
TypeError: doc.mUnbuild is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For QlikSense:

- [qlik-cli](https://qlik.dev/toolkits/qlik-cli/) - Qlik have a command line tool that can `unbuild` the app into its components and saves them into json and yaml files
- [enigma-mixin](https://github.com/countnazgul/enigma-mixin?tab=readme-ov-file#buildunbuild) - i've wrote an [enigma.js mixin](https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#mixins) that can be used from JS project to also "unbuild" an app into its components. Be aware that its not heavily tested
- Engine JSON API - the above solutions are using the Engine APIs to achieve its goals. So if you want something more specific then you'll have to use these APIs. The Engine APIs is the official (and only?) way to communicate with an app. This API can be used with any language that supports websockets

For QlikView:

Tthis functionality exists into QV itself. Have a look at [this tutorial](https://qlik.dev/toolkits/qlik-cli/) how to create xml files with the app components

**Update - Adding enigma-mixin example**

```js
import fs from "fs"
import WebSocket from "ws";
import enigma from "enigma.js";
import { docMixin } from "enigma-mixin";

const schema = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./node_modules/enigma.js/schemas/12.612.0.json"));

const session = enigma.create({
    schema,
    mixins: [...docMixin],
    url: "ws://127.0.0.1:4848/app/engineData",
    createSocket: (url) => new WebSocket(url),
});

async function run() {
    const global = await session.open()

    // change to your appId
    const doc = await global.openDoc("SOME-APP-ID-HERE")

    const entities = await doc.mUnbuild()

    await session.close()
}

run()
```

In the script above `enities` variable will have the following content:

[image: mUnbuild result]

Comment: I'm really impressed by your enigma-mixin code. I've managed to connect to my Qlik Desktop app, but I'm currently stuck. i am very new to most of this. Would you happen to have a code example that demonstrates the usage of the unbuild method?

Comment: Ive updated the answer with a small example

Comment: Thank you for your example! I really appreciate your help.

Now i receive the following error: 
const entities = await doc.mUnbuild()
                                 
TypeError: doc.mUnbuild is not a function

do you have an idea what the problem is? I provided the current code in the Question above. (i had to make a few changes to your script because it wouldnt run otherwise)

Comment: you should either do `mixins: docMixin` or `mixins: [...docMixin]`